# Foundation progress bar with text at full width

Tags: zurb-foundation

Foundation official document shows the usage of [progress bar with text](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/progress-bar.html). However, the text is within the filled part, and it breaks once the progress bar has 0% filled ([example](https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/xdpLdY)).

```
<div class="progress" role="progressbar" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuetext="25 percent" aria-valuemax="100">
  <span class="progress-meter" style="width: 0%">
    <p class="progress-meter-text">the text is broken here</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Is there anyway we could put the text at center of the entire progress bar, instead of the filled part?